# environment variable issue with procfile heroku

Tags: python, powershell, heroku, procfile

I am doing a Heroku tutorial and `web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT` creates the error when I run `heroku local` or `heroku local -p 5000` (or one of several more variants). However, `web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000` works fine. I suspect I am making a simple error with how to pass an environment variable into the Procfile.

The error message is: `CommandError: "0.0.0.0:$PORT" is not a valid port number or address:port pair.`

Comment: What is the error message? Please read [ask].

Comment: Hi @Chris I've worked out what was going wrong, and posted what now works below. However, I have edited the question to include the error message

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a difference between Windows and Linux. The solution is below for others' benefit.

on linux, `$PORT` references the variable called PORT

on windows, we instead need `%PORT%`

Hence, `web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:%PORT%` works for Procfile.windows. To run the Windows specific Procfile, run `heroku local web -f Procfile.windows` as the normal Procfile file should be left with `web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT` so it works when deployed (as heroku machines use linux)